# Element position relative to the viewport regarless of the scrollbar (cross browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, scrollbar

I am searching a cross browser solution to get the exact left/right position of an element in the viewport **regarless of the scrollbar**.

All solutions that I found on the web give solutions where the offset is counted from the right/left edge of the scrollbar (if any) and not from the edge of the viewport. **I want to get the offset left / right from the edge of the browser viewport**.

If there is no scrollbar, there is no problem. I can get the right / left position from viewport.

If there is a scrollbar, for example on the left of the `html` tag, if the `element` float on the left, it will have an offset left at 0, but i want an offset left at the width of the scrollbar (IE 16px, Chrome 17px...) which is the real offset from the viewport's left edge.

[image: scrollbar and element on the left]

[image: scrollbar and element on the right]

As we can see on these pictures, the left offsets are at 0 (but should be at the width of the scrollbar, here on IE at 16px) and for the right offsets we don't have any way to calculate them. Indeed, when the element float right, it will always be with an offset left at the size of the `innerWidth` of the window or at the size of the `body.clientWidth` (+ `element.clientWidth`) regardless if the scrollbar is on the left or on the right...

A good solution could have been to use `clientLeft` but it is not compatible with Safari, Edge and IE.

Another possible solution could have been to use `getBoundingClientRect().x` but the compatibility is very limited. Unfortunately, [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility) is mainly wrong for the x / y properties. The exact compatibility is :

- IE => not working
- Safari => v11 or more
- Opera => v48 or more
- Chrome => v61 or more
- Firefox => v52 or more
- Edge => not working

Note : To test and make the scrollbar / element on the left / right you can use this snippet :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    
    p {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: justify;
    }
    
    #sc {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sc"></div>
  <button id="toggle_scrollbar">toggle rtl / ltr</button>
  <button id="toggle_sc">toggle sc element</button>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
    eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>


  <script>
    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var sc = document.getElementById('sc');
    sc.style.float = 'right';
    
    var toggle_scrollbar = document.getElementById('toggle_scrollbar');
    toggle_scrollbar.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      html.setAttribute('dir', (html.getAttribute('dir') === 'rtl') ? 'ltr' : 'rtl');
      display();
    });
    
    var toggle_sc = document.getElementById('toggle_sc');
    toggle_sc.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      sc.style.float = (sc.style.float === 'right') ? 'left' : 'right';
      display();
    });

    function display () {
      console.log('window.pageXOffset ---> ', window.pageXOffset);
      console.log('window.scrollX ---> ', window.scrollX);
      console.log('window.innerWidth ---> ', window.innerWidth);
      console.log('window.outerWidth ---> ', window.outerWidth);
      console.log('element.offsetLeft ---> ', sc.offsetLeft);
      console.log('element.scrollLeft ---> ', sc.scrollLeft);
      console.log('element.clientLeft ---> ', sc.clientLeft);
      console.log('element.clientWidth ---> ', sc.clientWidth);
      console.log('element.getBoundingClientRect().left ---> ', sc.getBoundingClientRect().left);
      console.log('element.getBoundingClientRect().x ---> ', sc.getBoundingClientRect().x);
      console.log('body.offsetLeft ---> ', body.offsetLeft);
      console.log('body.scrollLeft ---> ', body.offsetLeft);
      console.log('body.clientLeft ---> ', body.clientLeft);
      console.log('body.clientWidth ---> ', body.clientWidth);
      console.log('body.getBoundingClientRect().left ---> ', body.getBoundingClientRect().left);
      console.log('body.getBoundingClientRect().x ---> ', body.getBoundingClientRect().x);
      console.log('document.documentElement.offsetLeft ---> ', document.documentElement.offsetLeft);
      console.log('document.documentElement.scrollLeft ---> ', document.documentElement.scrollLeft);
      console.log('document.documentElement.clientLeft ---> ', document.documentElement.clientLeft);
      console.log('document.documentElement.clientWidth ---> ', document.documentElement.clientWidth);
      console.log('html.offsetLeft ---> ', html.offsetLeft);
      console.log('html.scrollLeft ---> ', html.offsetLeft);
      console.log('html.clientLeft ---> ', html.clientLeft);
      console.log('html.clientWidth ---> ', html.clientWidth);
      console.log('html.getBoundingClientRect().left ---> ', html.getBoundingClientRect().left);
      console.log('html.getBoundingClientRect().x ---> ', html.getBoundingClientRect().x);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

(I changed the scrollbar on the `body` tag to make it works on chrome / Firefox, but i am searching a solution when the scroll is on the `html` tag too)

Does anyone have ideas to find a cross browser solution ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you don't use `position:fixed`, it's relative to the viewport

Comment: Just add or deduct  `window.innerWidth-document.body.offsetWidth` to the value that you get from the methods that you found in the net

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't want the element to be on the scrollbar (if any). I want the element to be on the right of the scrollbar as the normal behavior but to get the offset left from the viewport.

Comment: @evgenifotia Which methods ? `window.innerWidth` and `document.body.offsetWidth` won't help here.